# Mapdeck map will not load when called from a Shiny server over HTTP

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

I have created a Shiny app incorporating Mapdeck to visualize some pandemic-related data. When the app is run on my local machine using RStudio, it works just fine - the map, all layers, and all observer events work as expected.

However, to make the app accessible to others, I deployed it onto an ec2 Ubuntu instance running Shiny-server on port 80 (HTTP). For about a week, everything worked perfectly well - I could access it through my web browser and everything would load.

However, as of last week, when I access through my web browser, all parts of the app appear properly *except* that the map tiles themselves are not loaded (i.e., layers such as the grid and arcs are properly loaded - they're just sitting over white space). I have made no changes to my code over that time, and the version run on my local machine through RStudio still works fine.

When I interrogate the problem using the browser's console, I receive the following errors:

> Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.0/mapbox-gl.css' from origin 'http://**REDACTED**' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10?access_token=**REDACTED**' from origin 'http://**REDACTED**' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

Has this been observed over the past week or two by others? Is this a new browser security feature or does this mean that that the Mapbox API is now requiring that all requests come from an origin using HTTPS?

Comment: I think you are on the right direction. Most APIs nowadays are HTTPS. You can't mix up HTTP and HTTPS protocols on the same site. It will not be a problem in the testing environment, like localhost, but is not allowed in production (when you deploy). Strongly recommend you to change everything to HTTPS.